# Errors when attempting to useConfigureTestingModule in Angular2 test

Tags: angular, testing, dependency-injection, karma-runner

I am having errors whenever I attempt to create a testing module in my Angular2 application that used the TestBed.configureTestingModule method. This only happens when I try and include the component-under-test into the method. It also occurs when I attempt to load in a provider such as the Http class. I have been here for a day and a half now and have so far found no answers. Here is my code:

My product service. This contains dependencies on another service, HttpInterceptor, which itself extends the Http class. When I remove these DI out the problem disappears:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Product } from "../classes/Product";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { routes } from "../routes";
import { StringHelper } from "../helpers/StringHelper";
import { HttpHelper } from "../helpers/HttpHelper";
import { HttpInterceptor } from "./HttpInterceptor.service";

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
    public emitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    private APIUrl:String;

    constructor(
        private _http: HttpInterceptor
    ) {

    }

    getProduct(id:number): Observable<Product> {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http
            .get(routes.api.products  + '/' + id, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    /**
     * Get all products
     * return Observable
     */
    getProducts(filters:Object): Observable<Product[]> {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http
            .get(routes.api.products + StringHelper.convertVarsToString(filters), options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    editProduct(payload) {
        let headers = HttpHelper.createAuthorizationHeader(true, false);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        payload['_method'] = 'PUT';
        return this._http
            .post(routes.api.products + '/' + payload.product.id, payload, options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    /**
     * Add products to EventEmitter stream
     */
    public emitProducts(products): void {
        this.emitter.emit(products);
    }
}
```

The testing module. You can see I am attempting to use configureTestingModule to declare the service under test, and also include the HttpInterceptor class as a provider as this is DI'd into the productService service.

```
import {ProductService} from "../../services/product.service";
import {TestBed} from "@angular/core/testing";
import {HttpInterceptor} from "../../services/HttpInterceptor.service";
import {XHRBackend, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {GlobalEventsManager} from "../../services/globalEventsManager.service";

describe('Service: productService', () => {
    let prodService: ProductService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ProductService],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: HttpInterceptor,
                    useFactory: (
                        backend: XHRBackend,
                        defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                        authService: AuthService,
                        globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager
                    ) =>
                        new HttpInterceptor(backend, defaultOptions, authService, globalEventsManager),
                        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AuthService, GlobalEventsManager]
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

The errors I get in the console are:

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
consoleError @ zone.js:388
zone.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
```

From being sat here struggling for a day or so I have found that it is when I try and test or include components and services that have dependencies themselves which throws the error. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what that exact error means in this case, but just FYI, the `deps` in the provider object doesn't actually provide any providers. It is only used for reference for the factory injection. You still need to actually add the providers yourself into the `providers` array. You will also need to add the `HttpModule` to the `imports`. `RequestOptions` and `XHRBackend` still need some other dependencies that are provided by the `HttpModule`

Comment: Hi again and thanks for your help yet again. Can you just elaborate quickly as I am slightly confused by it all. I understand there is a problem with DI in the testing but it is unclear to me what the actual problem is

Comment: You see how you have the four provider classes in the `deps`. This doesn't actually add any providers. It is only used as reference for the `useFactory` injection. You still need to add all of those into the `providers` array. Also add `imports: [ HttpModule ]`, into the `configureTestingModule`

Comment: Ok thanks I understand. I have done what you said and still no success with this error. It's a real pain!!

Comment: You know what. I totally missed this. But again I am not sure if it is the problem. When testing, you should not use the real XHRBackend. You should use the MockBackend. Take a few minutes to [read this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html)